# How to group data into 10 second intevals?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns.

id  bigint,

rate decimal(18,2),

dateCreated datetime

I need the results to be grouped by 10 second interval.

Something like :

2019-12-15:00 13:20:10   avg(rate)

2019-12-15:00 13:20:20   avg(rate)

2019-12-15:00 13:20:30   avg(rate)

etc....

I am using SQL server 2017.

How do I accomplish that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Are there rows within _every_ 10 second interval? Do you need output for every 10 second interval even if there are no rows? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps truncating the datetime

**Example**

```
Select TrimTime = convert(varchar(18),dateCreated,120)+'0'
      ,AvgRate  = avg(Rate)
 From  YourTable
 Group By convert(varchar(18),dateCreated,120)
```

Comment: Brilliant - so simple it hurts. I was making a big ol' answer...but I think I'll stop before embarrassing myself ;-)

Comment: @Clay Thanks for the grin.  :)   Don't be shy about posting.  Feedback is how we all learn... and that's the fun part.

Comment: Aite - will do...I spent some time...might as well. But this is *the* answer

Comment: @VadimS Always happy to help.  I'm sure my wife would dispute the "genius" thing  :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a time table... let's call it TimeHacks...and it's divided into 10 second time spans. Maybe it looks something like

```
create table TimeHacks
( 
  IntervalNumber bigint, 
  DateTimeAtInterval datetime
)
```

Then it would be easy to join it to your table:

```
select 
  t.IntervalNumber,
  avg( y.rate )
from
  dbo.TimeHacks i
  inner join
  dbo.YourTable y
  on
    datediff( s, y.DateCreated, i.DateTimeAtInterval ) between 0 and 9
group by
  i.IntervalNumber
```

...and so the question is...do you make a table that has all those time hacks in it, or is there a better way?

So...now let's say that TimeHacks table isn't a table at all, but a SQL Server table valued function that takes 3 arguments, a start datetime, an end datetime and a number of seconds between hacks.

You could say something like:

```
select 
  i.IntervalNumber,
  avg( y.rate )
from
  dbo.TimeHacks( '2019-1-15 10:10:10', '2019-1-16 10:10:10', 10 )
  inner join
  dbo.YourTable y
  on
    datediff( s, y.DateCreated, i.DateTimeAtInterval ) between 0 and 9
group by
  i.id
```

Hmmm...but how to make that TimeHacks function? Let's imagine that we also have a table valued function that can generate arbitrary sequences of integers from any start to any end... like `dbo.FromTo( start bigint, end bigint )`. Then, our TimeHacks could be something like:

```
create function dbo.TimeHacks( @start datetime, @end datetime, @seconds int ) returns table as return
select
  ft.x as IntervalNumber,
  dateadd( s, ft.x * @seconds, @start ) DateTimeAtInterval
from
  dbo.FromTo( 0, datediff( s, @start, @end ) / @seconds ) ft
```

...and finally...how would we generate a sequence of numbers that forms the basis for our `dbo.TimeHacks` function? There's a number of answers to that question...some good ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers). I learned a lot from those answers. You might, too. Anyway, I've got a favorite version I've tweaked out of those answers. It makes a sequence of numbers without doing any I/O and can produce any sequence in order in the range of integers...and it's screaming fast:

```
create function dbo.FromTo( @start bigint, @end bigint ) returns table as return
with 
x0 as (select x from (values (0),(0x00000001),(0x00000002),(0x00000003),(0x00000004),(0x00000005),(0x00000006),(0x00000007),(0x00000008),(0x00000009),(0x0000000A),(0x0000000B),(0x0000000C),(0x0000000D),(0x0000000E),(0x0000000F)) as x0(x)),
x1 as (select x from (values (0),(0x00000010),(0x00000020),(0x00000030),(0x00000040),(0x00000050),(0x00000060),(0x00000070),(0x00000080),(0x00000090),(0x000000A0),(0x000000B0),(0x000000C0),(0x000000D0),(0x000000E0),(0x000000F0)) as x1(x)),
x2 as (select x from (values (0),(0x00000100),(0x00000200),(0x00000300),(0x00000400),(0x00000500),(0x00000600),(0x00000700),(0x00000800),(0x00000900),(0x00000A00),(0x00000B00),(0x00000C00),(0x00000D00),(0x00000E00),(0x00000F00)) as x2(x)),
x3 as (select x from (values (0),(0x00001000),(0x00002000),(0x00003000),(0x00004000),(0x00005000),(0x00006000),(0x00007000),(0x00008000),(0x00009000),(0x0000A000),(0x0000B000),(0x0000C000),(0x0000D000),(0x0000E000),(0x0000F000)) as x3(x)),
x4 as (select x from (values (0),(0x00010000),(0x00020000),(0x00030000),(0x00040000),(0x00050000),(0x00060000),(0x00070000),(0x00080000),(0x00090000),(0x000A0000),(0x000B0000),(0x000C0000),(0x000D0000),(0x000E0000),(0x000F0000)) as x4(x)),
x5 as (select x from (values (0),(0x00100000),(0x00200000),(0x00300000),(0x00400000),(0x00500000),(0x00600000),(0x00700000),(0x00800000),(0x00900000),(0x00A00000),(0x00B00000),(0x00C00000),(0x00D00000),(0x00E00000),(0x00F00000)) as x5(x)),
x6 as (select x from (values (0),(0x01000000),(0x02000000),(0x03000000),(0x04000000),(0x05000000),(0x06000000),(0x07000000),(0x08000000),(0x09000000),(0x0A000000),(0x0B000000),(0x0C000000),(0x0D000000),(0x0E000000),(0x0F000000)) as x6(x)),
x7 as (select x from (values (0),(0x10000000),(0x20000000),(0x30000000),(0x40000000),(0x50000000),(0x60000000),(0x70000000)) as x7(x))

select s.x
from 
    (
    select 
          x7.x
        | x6.x
        | x5.x
        | x4.x
        | x3.x
        | x2.x
        | x1.x
        | x0.x
        + @start
         x
    from 
        x7
        inner remote join x6 on x6.x <= @end - @start and x7.x <= @end - @start
        inner remote join x5 on x5.x <= @end - @start
        inner remote join x4 on x4.x <= @end - @start
        inner remote join x3 on x3.x <= @end - @start
        inner remote join x2 on x2.x <= @end - @start
        inner remote join x1 on x1.x <= @end - @start
        inner remote join x0 on x0.x <= @end - @start
    ) s
where @end >= s.x
```

The way this function works borders on magic. It's based on the question I referenced, and in particular it builds on the answers by [Brian Pressler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133693/1478654) and 
[mechoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49281857/1478654).

Comment: When I run my TVF https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e2624f62a8a7c925399c8493186a7642 vs your function... your's has a cost of 88% vs 12%

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, yer making me feel low, my friend! When I did the same locally...mine said 100% relative to batch and yours said 0% relative to batch...so I felt even lower. But I saw weirdness...I could *see* that mine appeared to run faster: looking in profiler, while mine took nearly twice the cpu, it consistently returned quicker. Parallelization? More investigating. I messed with yours to take `datetime, datetime,int` (secs)...so that it matched TimeHacks. Maybe I did bad? I don't know how to do the SO chat...but would love to continue this thread. I did 100 days in 1 sec intervals.

Comment: Let me dig into this a bit later.   Need to shovel before it turns into slush and then ice.   I'm so done with Winters.

Comment: Then I won't tell you how bad things are here in Florida ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very good and somewhat complex question.  I'm sorry you were treated so.  Take a look at [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455236/group-by-records-based-on-10-second-time-interval-in-sql-server) for a possible way of attacking it and good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Def a good start.  Plenty of ways to group by min... But grouping by seconds had me stumped...